# How to print a user control in PDF instead of xps?

Tags: wpf

When I want to print a user control, if I wanted to print to PDF, I have to covert the user control to a bitmap, if not, I get a blank page.

However, if I print to XPS, I get the pages.

Also I have realized this advantages of the XPS format:

- It is saved like vectorial objects, so I can zoom all I want I always get the better quality.
- If it is text, I can select the text.
- The size of the document is lower.

If I use a bitmap, the quality of text is worse, and I can't select it.

This is the code when I print it to PDF:

```
public static void ImprimirWpfToPdf(IEnumerable<dynamic> paramIeViewsParaImprimir, int paramFactorCalidad)
{
    FixedDocument miDocumento = new FixedDocument();

    DpiScale miDpiScaleDelSistema = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(0));



    for (int i = 0; i < paramIeViewsParaImprimir.Count(); i++)
    {
        paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).Arrange(new Rect(paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).DesiredSize));
        paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).UpdateLayout();

        Size miTamañoPagina = new Size(paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).ActualWidth, paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).ActualHeight);

        int miAncho = (int)Math.Round(miTamañoPagina.Width / 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 2;
        int miAlto = (int)Math.Round(miTamañoPagina.Height / 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 2;


        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging
        .RenderTargetBitmap(miAncho * paramFactorCalidad, miAlto * paramFactorCalidad, (miDpiScaleDelSistema.PixelsPerInchX / miDpiScaleDelSistema.DpiScaleX) * paramFactorCalidad, (miDpiScaleDelSistema.PixelsPerInchY / miDpiScaleDelSistema.DpiScaleY) * paramFactorCalidad, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bitmap.Render(paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i));


        System.Windows.Controls.Image myImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        myImage.Source = bitmap;


        //Se crea una página del documento. La primera, que tendrá los calendarios.
        FixedPage miPagina1 = new FixedPage();
        miPagina1.Width = miTamañoPagina.Width;
        miPagina1.Height = miTamañoPagina.Height;
        miPagina1.Children.Add(bitmap);


        PageContent miContenido1 = new PageContent();
        ((IAddChild)miContenido1).AddChild(miPagina1);

        miDocumento.Pages.Add(miContenido1);
    }




    System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog myDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

    if (myDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            //Print the image.
            myDialog.PrintDocument(miDocumento.DocumentPaginator, string.Empty);
        }
        catch
        {
            //@#MEJORAR: realmente una librería nunca debería tener un messagebox. Se tiene que lanzar una excepción.
            MessageBox.Show("El documento no se ha podido crear.\r\n\r\n"
                + "Si está abierto y se está intentando sobreescribir, se recomienda cerrar el documento antes"
                + " de imprimirlo.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code to print in XPS:

```
public static void ImprimirWpfToXps(IEnumerable<dynamic> paramIeViewsParaImprimir, int paramFactorCalidad)
{
    FixedDocument miDocumento = new FixedDocument();

    DpiScale miDpiScaleDelSistema = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(0));



    for (int i = 0; i < paramIeViewsParaImprimir.Count(); i++)
    {
        paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).Arrange(new Rect(paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).DesiredSize));
        paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).UpdateLayout();

        Size miTamañoPagina = new Size(paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).ActualWidth, paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i).ActualHeight);

        int miAncho = (int)Math.Round(miTamañoPagina.Width / 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 2;
        int miAlto = (int)Math.Round(miTamañoPagina.Height / 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 2;

  
        FixedPage miPagina1 = new FixedPage();
        miPagina1.Width = miTamañoPagina.Width;
        miPagina1.Height = miTamañoPagina.Height;
        miPagina1.Children.Add(paramIeViewsParaImprimir.ElementAt(i));


        PageContent miContenido1 = new PageContent();
        ((IAddChild)miContenido1).AddChild(miPagina1);

        miDocumento.Pages.Add(miContenido1);
    }




    System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog myDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

    if (myDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            //Print the image.
            myDialog.PrintDocument(miDocumento.DocumentPaginator, string.Empty);
        }
        catch
        {
            //@#MEJORAR: realmente una librería nunca debería tener un messagebox. Se tiene que lanzar una excepción.
            MessageBox.Show("El documento no se ha podido crear.\r\n\r\n"
                + "Si está abierto y se está intentando sobreescribir, se recomienda cerrar el documento antes"
                + " de imprimirlo.");
        }
    }
}
```

The unique difference between both is that, in the case of XPS, I don't create the bitmap and I add the user control directly to the fixed page.

This example code also it is needed to setup in windows as default printer, XPS printer or PDF printer in each case, but this has an easy solution.

Well, my question is, if in the XPS method version, if I have selected the Microsoft PDF Printer as default printer I get empty pages and if I print to XPS I get the pages that I want?

Thanks.

Comment: A simple call to `new PrintDialog().PrintVisual(myVisual, "Description");` will do it, but requires user interaction to define the destination file. .NET has no PDF printer. By calling the PrintDialog, WPF can make implicitly use of installed OS level PDF printers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The document is empty when I try to print a WPF user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71986694/the-document-is-empty-when-i-try-to-print-a-wpf-user-control)